# How to create context menu to change function of button

Tags: c#, wpf

So basically I am making a sort of menu that is full of buttons that opens different applications on my computer.
The issue I have is I would like to create a context menu of some sort that will allow me to change the location of the application it is searching for.
For example I am using

```
Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA GeForce Experience\\NVIDIA GeForce Experience.exe");
```

function to start the application but would like a menu I can access to change where the start function looks for the application in case I am to change the location of any applications.

Example of code for button:

```
<Button x:Name="SYSTEM1_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="130" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

I haven't tried anything as I am very new to WPF coding and have no idea what I am doin.

Comment: Please embed code as code, and not images.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited it and embeded the code now.
I am also new to this page.

Comment: What is the `ContextMenu` supposed to do? How many options are there?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Is the desired behavior to have the ability to change the executable path at runtime? Can you give an example of the desired behavior?